# Simplify $P(A|(B \text{ or } C))$

Tags: probability

I am wondering that what is probability

$$P(A|(B \text{ or } C))$$

given that $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive. Is it decomposable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:

$$P(A|B\cup C)=\frac{P(A\cap(B\cup C))}{P(B\cup C)}=\frac{P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cup C))}{P(B\cup C)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)}{P(B)+P(C)}$$

**EDIT** In case of simplify, alternative forms are

$\begin{eqnarray}
P(A|B\cup C)&=&P(B\cup C|A)\frac{P(A)}{P(B\cup C)}\\
&=&\frac{P(A)}{P(B\cup C)}[P(B|A)+P(C|A)]\\
&=&\frac{P(A)}{P(B)+ P(C)}[P(B|A)+P(C|A)]
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! But is there any way to express it into two or more conditional probability with only one element in the given part. Or with only one probability in the denominator?

Comment: @J.Y. No.  That's as simply as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
P(A|(B\cup C))  &= \frac{P(A(B\cup C))}{P(B\cup C))}\\
&= \frac{P(AB\cup AC)}{P(B)+P(C)-P(BC)}\tag1\\
&=\frac{P(AB)+P(AC)-P(ABC)}{P(B)+P(C)-P(BC)}\tag2\\
&=\frac{P(AB)+P(AC)-0}{P(B)+P(C)-0}\\
&=\frac{P(AB)+P(AC)}{P(B)+P(C)}
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I distributed the event $A$ and used inclusion-exclusion, and in $(2)$ I used inclusion-exclusion and I recognize that
$$P(ABC)=P(BC) = P(\varnothing) = 0.$$